# Keycloack with mysql and docker-compose not working

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm trying to create a docker-compose to run keycloak with mysql.

But my keycloack keep exiting with this error: `Failed to connect to database`

This is the full error

```
01:04:39,962 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@18.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:420)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@18.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@18.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@18.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:756)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@18.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@18.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:136)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@18.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:242)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@18.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:130)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@18.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:36)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@18.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:116)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.constructOutsideRequest(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:225)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:209)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.Utils.createProviderInstance(Utils.java:102)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:1385)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.createApplication(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:418)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.initializeObjects(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:265)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:137)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:121)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.doIt(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:76)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.16.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:106)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)
        at org.jboss.as.connector@26.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@18.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:414)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:364)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:371)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1328)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:505)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:640)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:605)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'keycloak'@'192.168.32.3' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:335)
```

My docker-compose.yaml file is like this

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: keycloak_mysql
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 33306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=keycloak
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
  app:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_ADDR=db
      - DB_VENDOR=MYSQL
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Edi1:

I realized that if I change the volume to local it works

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: keycloak_mysql
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 33306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=keycloak
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
  app:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_ADDR=db
      - DB_VENDOR=MYSQL
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
```

But I  wish to use with a folder inside my repo, like on the original yam `./.docker/dbdata`